# Get instagram followers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, instagram, screen-scraping

I want to parse a website's followers count with BeautifulSoup. This is what I have so far:

```
username_extract = 'lazada_my'

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'+ username_extract
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
f = soup.find('head', attrs={'class':'count'})
```

This is the part I want to parse:

[image]

Something within my soup.find() function is wrong, but I can't wrap my head around it. When returning f, it is empty. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: for getting instagram data i would suggest you to use [python-instagram](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use re module to search the correct count.

```
import requests
import re

username_extract = 'lazada_my'

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'+ username_extract
r = requests.get(url)
m = re.search(r'"followed_by":\{"count":([0-9]+)\}', str(r.content))
print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. Mind explaining the logic behind using re and not beautifulsoup? Still new to web scraping, and I thought beautifulsoup is best practice.

Comment: @calicationoflife I wonder you are not using the solution of blender, He cleared explained.

Comment: @calicationoflife, beautifulsoup can't scrape the data which located inside the `<script>` tag since it is in the form of `.text`. So, bs4 can only get the script text, but not parse it on its own.

Comment: perform the regular expression on entire page is not a good idea.

Comment: @Keyur: I used William's solution because it is easier to plug into the remaining code I already had. But all your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Most of the content is dynamically generated with JS. That's the reason you're getting empty results.

But, the `followers` count is present in the page source. Only thing is, it is not directly available in the form you want. You can see it here:

```
<meta content="407.4k Followers, 27 Following, 2,740 Posts - See Instagram photos and videos from Lazada Malaysia (@lazada_my)" name="description" />
```

If you want to scrape the followers count without regex, you can use this:

```
>>> followers = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'description'})['content']
>>> followers
'407.4k Followers, 27 Following, 2,740 Posts - See Instagram photos and videos from Lazada Malaysia (@lazada_my)'
>>> followers_count = followers.split('Followers')[0]
>>> followers_count
'407.4k '
```

Answer (score 2):

`soup.find('head', attrs={'class':'count'})` searches for something that looks like `<head class="count">`, which doesn't exist anywhere in the HTML. The data you're after is contained in the `<script>` tag that starts with `window._sharedData`:

```
script = soup.find('script', text=lambda t: t.startswith('window._sharedData'))
```

From there, you can just strip off the variable assignment and the semicolon to get valid JSON:

```
# <script>window._sharedData = ...;</script>
#                              ^^^
#                              JSON

page_json = script.text.split(' = ', 1)[1].rstrip(';')
```

Parse it and everything you need is contained in the object:

```
import json

data = json.loads(page_json)
follower_count = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['user']['followed_by']['count']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for the `scripts`, Then look for the `'window._sharedData'` exits in it. If exits then perform the regular expression operation.

```
import re

username_extract = 'lazada_my'
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'+ username_extract
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
s = re.compile(r'"followed_by":{"count":\d*}')
for i in soup.find_all('script'):
     if 'window._sharedData' in str(i):
         print s.search(str(i.contents)).group()
```

**Result,**

```
"followed_by":{"count":407426}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I ended up using William's solution. In case anybody will have future projects, here is my complete code for scraping a bunch of URL's for their follower count:

```
import requests
import csv 
import pandas as pd
import re

insta = pd.read_csv('Instagram.csv')

username = []

bad_urls = [] 

for lines in insta['Instagram'][0:250]:
    lines = lines.split("/")
    username.append(lines[3])

with open('insta_output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
t = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')     #   ----> COMMA Seperated
for user in username:
   try:
       url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'+ user
       r = requests.get(url)
       m = re.search(r'"followed_by":\{"count":([0-9]+)\}', str(r.content))
       num_followers = m.group(1)
       t.writerow([user,num_followers])    #  ----> Adding Rows
   except:
       bad_urls.append(url)
```