# Scraping Instagram with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a particular string from the "search by tag" in Instagram.
I'd like to get the url img from here:

```
<img alt="#yeşil  #manzara #doğa  
#yayla #nature #naturelovers #adventuretime #adventures #mountainstaries 
#picture #şehirdenuzak  #tatil #holiday #cow  #potography #view #kütükev 
#naturelife #animal #amazing  #kar #winter #winteriscomming #mapavr1 #artvin 
#tulumile #insaatr #tulumci #rize 
class="_2di5p" sizes="171px" srcset="https://scontent-mxp11.cdninstagram.com/vp/c883e0c4267c003843fafeda255f1329/5A9D3C97/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/c0.90.720.720/28154674_2016914221854461_991623208941649920_n.jpg 150w,
https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6a3480f8658b50c691bcc100a96cc6f0/5A9CC9DC/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/c0.90.720.720/28154674_2016914221854461_991623208941649920_n.jpg 240w,
https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/461c138e15f52420c3fbc075fab027eb/5A9DD808/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/c0.90.720.720/28154674_2016914221854461_991623208941649920_n.jpg 320w,
https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ad5d67f1c9ea77d78d145501e73c2ea0/5A9CAF9D/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e15/c0.90.720.720/28154674_2016914221854461_991623208941649920_n.jpg 480w,
https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e0636f79adc1ae53f7321d10fe60f275/5A9CD134/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/c0.90.720.720/28154674_2016914221854461_991623208941649920_n.jpg 640w" 
src="https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e0636f79adc1ae53f7321d10fe60f275/5A9CD134/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/c0.90.720.720/28154674_2016914221854461_991623208941649920_n.jpg" style="">
```

so basically I wolud like to get this string (That is the one with 240w at the end):

```
https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6a3480f8658b50c691bcc100a96cc6f0/../n.jpg
```

and I tried writing this code with Python but it doesn't work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/nature/")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
element = soup.find("srcset")
print(element.text.strip())
```

maybe the real problem is that there are 21 elements like this one in the page
but to start I'd like to understand how to get that string.

(And, if any of you know a good tutorial or book for bs4 can you tell me?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't see any output is that the images are added dynamically to the page source using JavaScript. So, the HTML that you've provided isn't available in the page source. Easiest way to overcome this is to use [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

But, there's one more way to scrape that. Looking at the page source, the data you're after, is available in a `<script>` tag in the form of JSON. The relevant data is in the form of:

```
"thumbnail_resources": [
    {
        "src": "https://instagram.fpnq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a3ed0ee1af581f1c1fe6170b8c080e7c/5B2CA660/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/28433503_571483933190064_5347634166450094080_n.jpg",
         "config_width": 150,
         "config_height": 150
     },
     {
         "src": "https://instagram.fpnq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7a0bb4fb1b5d5e3b179c58a2b9472b9f/5B2C535F/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e35/28433503_571483933190064_5347634166450094080_n.jpg",
         "config_width": 240,
         "config_height": 240
     },
```

To get the JSON, you can use this (code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49044294/7832176)):

```
script = soup.find('script', text=lambda t: t.startswith('window._sharedData'))
page_json = script.text.split(' = ', 1)[1].rstrip(';')
data = json.loads(page_json)
```

Code to get image link for all the images:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/nature/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

script = soup.find('script', text=lambda t: t.startswith('window._sharedData'))
page_json = script.text.split(' = ', 1)[1].rstrip(';')
data = json.loads(page_json)

for post in data['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges']:
    image_src = post['node']['thumbnail_resources'][1]['src']
    print(image_src)
```

Partial output:

```
https://instagram.fpnq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e8a78407fb61de834cad7f10eca830fc/5A9DC375/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/c0.80.640.640/28766397_174603559842180_1092148752455565312_n.jpg
https://instagram.fpnq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/3a20f36647c86c2196f259b5d14ebf82/5A9D5BC9/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/28433802_283862648812409_3322859933120069632_n.jpg
https://instagram.fpnq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/82216be4596dd9da862ba267cdeab517/5B144226/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/28157436_941679549319762_5605299824451649536_n.jpg
https://instagram.fpnq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e50eab90b2e0951d67922e49b495e1fc/5B3EC9B8/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e35/c135.0.810.810/28754107_179533402825352_1137703808411893760_n.jpg
https://instagram.fpnq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d3a13e7b81a65421b4318b57fb8ee24e/5B4D9EFF/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e35/28433583_375555202918683_1951892035636035584_n.jpg
https://instagram.fpnq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/1b0aeea1b9be983498192d350e039aa0/5B43C583/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e35/28156427_154249191953160_9219472301039288320_n.jpg
...
```

**Note:** The `[1]` in the line `image_src = post['node']['thumbnail_resources'][1]['src']` is for 240w. You can use 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 for 150w, 240w, 320w, 480w or 640w respectively. Also, if you want any other data regarding any image, like, number of likes, comments, caption, etc; everything is available in this JSON (`data` variable).

Comment: @fobu36, the last question if off-topic for SO. But here you go- The best resource for learning BeautifulSoup is the [**DOCUMENTATION**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)  (sorry for the caps, but it really is the best resource available).

Comment: It's a very nice approach @Keyur Potdar. Your solution should have already been selected. However, I've got a question concerning `lambda`. You started the function `text=lambda`. It is not just a placeholder, I believe. As I'm a newbie in `lambda` so I cant relate this `text`. A oneliner comment as to where does this `text` come from will suffice . Thanks.

Comment: @SIM, as mentioned in the answer, I got that line from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043857/get-instagram-followers/49044294#49044294). While I get how it works, I don't think I can explain it properly (since I'm a newbie for `lambda` too). You say *the function starts with `text=lambda`*; but in reality it is `text = (lambda t: t.startswith...)`. If that part was obvious to you, I'm sorry, I can't explain it in any other way. I don't want to give any incorrect/incomplete explanation.

Comment: Don't bother. That means replacing `text` with `string` will also work. Thanks.

Comment: @SIM, Hah! I thought you were asking me about the working of `lambda`. To answer your question, the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) say - *The `string` argument is new in Beautiful Soup 4.4.0. In earlier versions it was called `text`*