# Unable to get response from a webpage

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

I am unable to crawl below web page

https://www.sunnxt.com/tv/detail/41600/

This web page have episodes of shows. I require episodes name and their dates.

when I tried to parse it with css or xpath selector it is not giving me required response.

I have tried with below code in scrapy:

```
Request(url="https://www.sunnxt.com/tv/detail/32574/", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                                              "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36", "csrf-token":"lRXDyfu9trir3WDggGqAGYlefUNEaCJ7b8dvI33g"}, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.get_episodes)

def get_episodes(self, response):
    item = response.meta.get('item')
    for x in response.css('body'):
        item['code'] = x.css('script::text').extract()
```

Could somebody please help.

Comment: *not giving me required response*? Please [edit] the post and add what you tried, what's your expected output, and what output you're currently getting.

Comment: Show what you have tried (code).

Comment: Looks like the content is loaded using JavaScript, which is why you're getting different response. But, the content you want is available in the page source in the form of JSON in one of the `script` tags. Try to apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086016/7832176) for this website. It's pretty much the same.

Comment: to get html page, this web page require csrf token and user agent, I have set both and then it gives html page. In the html page there is lots of <script> tag containing json formated text. I need them to convert them into python object and then will iterate the to get required data

Comment: Looks like you've done most of the work. Why don't you add that code in the question?

Comment: Added my code in question. actually there are multiple script tags so getting multiple json object with some php text that is why it looks hard to me