# Cannot find script tag for getting json code

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

I want to scrape the data from one username on Instagram platform. However, I cannot find where is the JSON code located on tag. I have read several quetions related to my issue but still being stucked.

Here are my current code

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('c:/Users/rukma/Downloads/Software/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+username+'/?hl=en')
source = browser.page_source
data=bs(source, 'html.parser') 
body = data.find('body') 
script =data.find('script')
print(script.prettify())
```

Afte I checked on script tag, the result are as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
  var docElement = document.documentElement;
  var classRE = new RegExp('(^|\\s)no-js(\\s|$)');
  var className = docElement.className;
  docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, '$1js$2');
})();
</script>
```

I am focusing on find script to get JSON code since I read this solutions [Scraping Instagram with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085421/scraping-instagram-with-beautifulsoup)

Did I something miss or wrong with my code?

Comment: what kind of the data you want to scrap? do you mean this: https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1

Comment: I  did the similar thing using selenium and this api. It can be found here: https://github.com/ninjakx/Insta-card-generator. Hope that helps

Comment: I want to scrap my account just for try its worked or not. however. I want to scrap IG Feed first of any account or for the next wanna scrap other data like stories or anything that possible to scrap.

Comment: hallo @Pygirl, I don't want what happened. After this now I try again, suddenly the code that contain JSON code was found. Even I do not anything, just rewrite the code and its worked. thank you btw for your help before